# How to convert ruby array to C array with RubyInline?

Tags: c, ruby

I have a function which compares 2 strings char by char. I needed it to run much faster than it  is in Ruby so I used RubyInline to rewrite the function in C. It did increase the speed about 100 fold. The function looks like this:

```
  require 'inline'

  inline do |builder|
    builder.c "
      static int distance(char *s, char *t){
        ...
      }"
  end
```

however I need to compare unicode strings. So I decided to use unpack("U*") and compare arrays of integers instead. I cannot figure out from a scanty documentation to RubyInline how to pass the ruby arrays into the function and how to convert them into C arrays. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No problem, let me know how it turns out. Would love to see your implementation when done.

Comment: Here is the code of damerau_levenshtein distance:

http://gist.github.com/147023

For ruby 1.8.7 works like a charm, but chokes on ruby 1.9.1

Comment: I updated http://gist.github.com/147023  to work with 1.9.1 ruby as well using help from thnetos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has a good rundown of how to access Ruby objects from C: http://rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ext_ruby.html

```
inline do |builder|
  builder.c "
    static VALUE some_method(VALUE s) {
      int s_len = RARRAY(s)->len;
      int result = 0;

      VALUE *s_arr = RARRAY(s)->ptr;

      for(i = 0; i < s_len; i++) {
        result += NUM2INT(s_arr[i]); // example of reference
      }

      return INT2NUM(result); // convert C int back into ruby Numeric 
    }"
end
```

Then in ruby you can just pass values to it like:

```
object.some_method([1,2,3,4])
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks Corban, it looks exactly what I need!

Answer (score 4):

Given the code from the above answer, here is the code that will work for Ruby 1.8.6 *and* 1.9.1:

```
inline do |builder|
  builder.c "
    static VALUE some_method(VALUE s) {
      int s_len = RARRAY_LEN(s);
      int result = 0;
      int i = 0;

      VALUE *s_arr = RARRAY_PTR(s);

      for(i = 0; i < s_len; i++) {
        result += NUM2INT(s_arr[i]); // example of reference
      }

      return INT2NUM(result); // convert C int back into ruby Numeric 
    }"
end
```

Hope this helps also :)

Comment: Thanks thnetos, it did fix the problem, I updated the github gist example