# How can i access the value of a ruby array in C? (editing array.c:rb_ary_initialize from ruby source code)

Tags: c, ruby, arrays, debugging, gdb

```
arr=Array.new(3)
arr[0]=5
arr[1]=3
arr[2]=2
```

These lines should call this function, https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L568 according to this, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html

So I have added couple of lines there to display the values of array. But i didn't get the expected result.

```
else {
    memfill(RARRAY_PTR(ary), len, val);
    ARY_SET_LEN(ary, len);
    int i;
    int result;
    result = 0;
    VALUE *s_arr = RARRAY_PTR(ary);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        result = LONG2NUM(s_arr[i]);
        printf("r: %d\n",result);
    }
}
```

I got the result like this:

```
arr=Array.new(3)
arr[0]=5
arr[1]=3
arr[2]=2
r: 9
r: 9
r: 9
```

Why is this result? Why 9?

I have followed these to solve it:

- [How to convert ruby array to C array with RubyInline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117180/how-to-convert-ruby-array-to-c-array-with-rubyinline)
- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/README.EXT#L131
- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/include/ruby/ruby.h#L708
- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/include/ruby/ruby.h#L731

Can anyone please help to display/printf the value of Ruby array in C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense:

```
result = LONG2NUM(s_arr[i]);
```

`LONG2NUM` is used to convert a C `long int` to a Ruby `VALUE` that holds a number; `s_arr[i]` is already a `VALUE` so you're effectively doing things like `VALUE v = LONG2NUM((VALUE)5)`. `LONG2NUM` is defined in `ruby.h` as a wrapper for this:

```
#define LONG2NUM_internal(v) (FIXABLE(v) ? LONG2FIX(v) : rb_int2big(v))
```

and if `v` fits in a `VALUE` without converting it to a bignum, then you end up using this:

```
#define INT2FIX(i) ((VALUE)(((SIGNED_VALUE)(i))<<1 | FIXNUM_FLAG))
```

So you're basically doing a bunch of bit wrangling on a pointer and wondering why it always says `9`; consider yourself lucky (or unlucky) that it doesn't say *segmentation fault*.

You want to convert a `VALUE` which holds a number to a C integer. You probably want to use `FIX2LONG`:

```
#define FIX2LONG(x) (long)RSHIFT((SIGNED_VALUE)(x),1)
```

or `NUM2LONG`:

```
#define NUM2LONG_internal(x) ((long)(FIXNUM_P(x) ? FIX2LONG(x) : rb_num2long(x)))
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define NUM2LONG(x) \
    __extension__ ({VALUE num2long_x = (x); NUM2LONG_internal(num2long_x);})
#else
static inline long
NUM2LONG(VALUE x)
{
    return NUM2LONG_internal(x);
}
#endif
```

So something like this:

```
long result;
for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result = NUM2LONG(s_arr[i]);
    printf("r: %ld\n", result);
}
```

Note the switch to `%ld` since we're using `long`s now and we always turn on all the picky compiler flags that complain about mismatched `printf` formats and arguments. Of course, this assumes that you are certain that the array contains numbers that will fit in a C `long`.

Comment: Using NUM2LONG, i got this, `t.rb:3:in initialize': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
 from t.rb:3:in new
 from t.rb:3:in <main>'`

Comment: @prime: I don't know what line three of `t.rb` is.

Comment: @prime: That error is probably coming from `rb_num2long` in `numeric.c` and means that you're trying to use `NUM2LONG` on a Ruby `nil` value. Are you sure you're not running off the end of the array or something similar?

Comment: t.rb contains these lines, `arr=Array.new(3)
arr[0]=5
arr[1]=3
arr[2]=2
`